# Issue enabling Wechat pay with Stripe API

Tags: php, stripe-payments, wechat

I am developer trying to integrate Wechat pay with Stripe API on my website to accept payments from China. I have been facing issues whether the user needs to be redirected to the source object->wechat->qr_code_url or we just need to display that URL and that will display the qr code. As on the test side we need to redirect user to wechat test pay page. If we do that how are we supposed to track source object status with web hooks. I am landing on the wechat test page but unable to track source object status after that. Need help from anyone experienced at this.

Comment: Hi, you would need to listen to event webhook to monitor the status of the source 
https://stripe.com/docs/sources/wechat-pay. The source status will become `source.chargable` when user authorized it through QR code.

Answer (score 0):

Stripe Itself make it enable, usually they took 24 or less hours to review your request and response on it, so you should sit free and wait for their action.

Answer (score 0):

using js plugin like

https://cdn.rawgit.com/davidshimjs/qrcodejs/gh-pages/qrcode.min.js
please use below code

```
const qrCode = new QRCode('wechat-qrcode', {
                                text: qr_code_url,
                                width: 128,
                                height: 128,
                                colorDark: '#424770',
                                colorLight: '#f8fbfd',
                                correctLevel: QRCode.CorrectLevel.H,
                            });
```

wechat-qrcode is a selector.